# Windows Vista - Error Code '0x45d'

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, code

When I went to turn on my laptop today, I got the error code '0x45d'. What does this error code mean and how can I fix whatever the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of hits on [google for this error](http://www.google.com/search?q=Error+Code+%270x45d%27) the common advise seems to be:

> Try to boot into safe mode and restore to last known working configuration. If that doesn't work run a repair with your Vista installation DVD.